# mod_rewrite one folder somewhere

Tags: mod-rewrite, spam

Hi i hve been running forum for quite while and people started using it for spam etc and now even though i took it down i still got like 100 clicks day for threads that dont exist and the forum is not existing too.

I tired of seeing this crap in my piwik stats i want to move it with mod rewrite so every time someone access

site.com/samples/forum he goes soemwhere else like actual redirect to fbi.com etc. better without showing my url of couse or just to some non existing folder so it does not triger my stats.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /samples/forum http://othersite.com/path [L,R]
```

(of course can flex if you need patterns, or for different paths) There are tons of handy options that you can use, all documented in [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).